# Gracefully shut down an Elasticsearch master node

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch cluster with separate dedicated data noes and master nodes. I known how to [shut down a data node](/questions/17268495/how-to-remove-node-from-elasticsearch-cluster-on-runtime-without-down-time) gracefully. What is the corresponding procedure for shutting down a master node?

- Is there any data stored on a master node which is not fully duplicated on every other master node?

  - If so, how do I tell Elasticsearch that this master node is going down, so it should evacuate that data?
  - If not, how do I check if the nodes are in sync before taking one down?
- Is there some way to tell the active master that I want to take it down, so it should finish anything it is doing, then hand over to one of the other master-candidates?